# Nice way for accesing interface path

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Please help to find a  solution, for having nice looking code.

So in my code I have to do several forcing, as the same wire is being driven by tb and other part of design. As a result I have lots of force statements like this:

force TOP.u_proto_mc_top.gtx_rx_reset = **TOP.u_proto_mc_top.u_GTX_RXB.gtxMaster_itf_inst**.rstn;

force TOP.u_proto_mc_top.gtx_tx_reset = **TOP.u_proto_mc_top.u_GTX_RXB.gtxMaster_itf_inst**.txstn;

So I am just copy pasting the same interface path again and again, I mean this path:
**`TOP.u_proto_mc_top.u_GTX_RXB.gtxMaster_itf_inst`**

Each time I need to force a interface signal, I have to copy and paste this path.
This is ugly to me.
Can someone please suggest another solution to this, for I don’t copy/paste the interface path again and again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First I would try to find out why the structure of your testbench requires a force with an interface. Better planing could possibly avoid this.

A quick solutions use to use a text macro.

```
`define uTOP TOP.u_proto_mc_top 
`define GTXMaster `uTOP.u_GTX_RXB.gtxMaster_itf_inst
force `uTOP.gtx_tx_reset = `GTXMaster.txstn;
```

Comment: I have a GTX module in the middle of my hierarchy, my test bench at first test GTX link by sending some data through that GTX module, after making sure that GTX link is on it runs top level test.
    assign mc_rx_update = rx_reg_we | rx_update;
     GTX    u_GTX_RXB (  .update (mc_rx_update), .. )
So I have a interface which contains all GTX ports in it. And then I am binding that interface to GTX module.
Here if we take update signal, in one side it is being driven by my driver module, on another side the “mc_rx_update” is also trying to drive it. Mostly “mc_rx_update” is X .

Comment: As a result I am getting 2 different drivers on a single net, hence comes Xs.
To solve this I am creating force_signal and release_signal tasks, which will force the “mc_rx_update”  to the interface ports.

Answer (score 1):

You can use uvm_hdl_read() and uvm_hdl_force() instead?  Those UVM built-in function takes a string as input argument for the hdl path.

```
string if_path = "TOP.u_proto_mc_top.u_GTX_RXB.gtxMaster_itf_inst";
string top_path = "TOP.u_proto_mc_top";
uvm_hdl_data_t val;

uvm_hdl_read({if_path,".rstn"}, val);
uvm_hdl_force({top_path, ".gtx_rx_reset", val);

uvm_hdl_read({path,".txstn"}, val);
uvm_hdl_force({top_path, ".gtx_tx_reset", val);
```

Comment: hmm, and what is the benefit of this syntax?
does uvm_hdl_force give any useful options to user

Comment: The benefit is the hdl_path inside the quote is just a text string.  You can build different string or bind to different DUT hierarchy at run time.  Define hdl path using text macro is hard coded in compile time and make the code harder to reuse.